# variable?: type and variable: type | undefined = unedfined is equals in TS?

Tags: typescript

My colleague does not agree with me about the fact that

`variable?: type`

and

`variable: type | undefined = unedfined`

are equivalent, hence I want to find out the truth. How `?: type` does work under the hood?

What if

`variable?: type`

and

`variable: type | undefined`

Then are they equivalent?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes

Comment: They are equivalent, unless you have `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` enabled.

Comment: Either Dimava or pink should maybe write up an answer with the [doc link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) that explains the situation

Comment: Honestly I'm surprized there is no obvious duplicate question. Seems like it actually needs an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't equivalent.

```
type OptionalX = {x?: number}
type RequiredX = {x: number | undefined}

const opt: OptionalX = {}; // OK
const req: RequiredX = {}; // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwBpQLxQG8APAfgC4oUBXAWwCMIAnAXwChRIoAlCARyoSMIAExz5iFavSZQAPlCophEAGYIUItqwDGqAM7AoSeBTiJUmMYWYBuKAHp7sANI79hobwo9+gkVYJbBycmRiRGViA)

That said, it is worth mentioning that specifically in a class, the following *are* equivalent if you enable the `useDefineForClassFields` flag:

```
class OptionalX {
    x?: number;
}

class RequiredX {
    x: number | undefined = undefined;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyAOAXAlgewHZhADWgbwChpjoAPAfgC5p0BXAWwCMBTAJwG4CBfAg0SGACVmAR1rJWzACa5CJMtTpM20AD7Ra6KcwBmydNOgBeDVt37pnHkA)

This is because when this flag is enabled, the emitted code is like `class OptionalX { x; }`, so that the field `x` is declared, and its initial value will be `undefined` since it has no initialiser.

---

Note that neither of these depend on the `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` flag. That flag only controls whether `x?: number` is equivalent to `x?: number | undefined`, where both have the `?` indicating an optional property.